# JavaMaildir error: No provider for maildir

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-mail, maildir

I'm trying to develop an e-mail client for android using JavaMail and JavaMaildir. I've downloaded JavaMaildir from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javamaildir/, version `0.5`.

I've added the `.jar` file into the `libs` folder of my android project. The project compiles without problem.

Here is the code I'm using to initialize the store object:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.store.maildir.autocreatedir", true);
this.session = Session.getInstance(prop);
// Creates the directory if it doesn't exists
File dir = this.getDir(POP3ClientService.md_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String url = "maildir:" + dir.getAbsolutePath();
Log.d("DEBUG", url);
try {
    this.store = this.session.getStore(new URLName(url));
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    this.store = null;
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
}
```

http://javamaildir.sourceforge.net/examples/
Which is taken from the example available on the project site: http://javamaildir.sourceforge.net/examples/

Unfortunately, it throws a `NoSuchProviderException` and therefore I cannot use the store since it's a null pointer.

The error message says `No provider for maildir`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is the jar file available at runtime?  If you turn on JavaMail session debugging, what does the output show?

Comment: @BillShannon, How am I supposed to read the JavaMail session debugging on  Android? Is there any way to redirect logs to Logcat?

Comment: Cause I've added `session.setDebug(true)` to my code, but I don't see any extra log line in Logcat, even if it seems it should be automatically redirected to Logcat.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Android.  You can always redirect the JavaMail debug output using Session.setDebugOut.